# I just wrote my first app, powered by xstate, I love the visualizer tool. How can I programmatically generate the diagrams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, fsm, xstate

I keep having to remove all of my variable references and other bits and pieces when I use the visualizer tool to generate those useful diagrams.
I was wondering if there is a way for me to generate them programmatically?

Is there a typescript compatible or even a non-typescript method of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is currently in progress. If you would like to see progress (or are brave enough to try it out yourself), it is on the `viz` branch of XState: https://github.com/davidkpiano/xstate/tree/viz